# How to show TimeSpan with cumulated hours?

Tags: c#, winforms, formatting, timespan

I receive imports from an external source where the timespan fields are stored in seconds.
To convert these to a timespan I currently do this

```
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(140520)
```

This results in a timespan that displays `1 15:02:00`
What I would like is that it displays `39:02:00`

How can I do this ?

Comment: The duplicate is exact what I was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 3):

The `TotalHours` property of the resulting TimeSpan should give you the first part of what you want:

```
var timespan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(140520);
//If you cast the TotalHours to int you will get '39'
int totalHours = (int)timespan.TotalHours;

//If you want the '2' that would result from your input of 140520 you will need the minutes property
int minutes = timespan.Minutes;
```

Comment: So you are saying I should build the result myself, using the Hours property of the timestamp ? Something like timeSpan.TotalHours.ToString() + ":" + timeSpan.Minutes; ?

Comment: I made a working function with this info, thanks